# Truncando dados ao inserir no banco

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

O sistema está em um host comum com as seguintes config:

- Apache 2.4.25
- PHP 5.4.45
- MySQL 5.5.58-cll

É destinado ao controle de O.S. e cada usuário possui um login com sua senha.
Durante o desenvolvimento e testes estava tudo OK, porém vem acontecendo, agora que foi liberado para os usuários, do sistema misturar dados das O.S. De início desconfiei de algo envolvendo as sessões, mas lendo sobre, acabou não fazendo muito sentido, pois ocorre também entre usuários que nem estão na mesma rede.
Ex.:

- Usuário X está editando a O.S 01
- Usuário Y está editando a O.S 02

Quando X salva sua O.S. (AJAX prepara os dados e envia via POST para salvar.php) a página recarrega com alguns dados da O.S de Y
Nem sempre são os mesmos dados e nem sempre acontece.

Não sei onde/como procurar o problema, tanto que gostaria de fornecer o código para análise, mas sequer imagino que parte dele eu poderia incluir aqui.

O problema pode mesmo ser a sessão?
Pode ser alguma limitação do servidor?
Ou pode mesmo estar no script salvar.php sendo utilizado simultaneamente?
Desconfiei também do config.php (acesso ao banco), pois utiliza um só usuário. Isso tem alguma relação ou o que difere o acesso é a sessão?

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo ou print de dados truncados e não truncados? Para tentar verificar se há algum padrão. Truncando seria cortando uma informação ou seria que como há 2 usuários mexendo no mesmo registro acaba sobrescrevendo o do outro?

Comment: [imagens](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByPNDqTUymUPUWFQc3lrdFI1dEE?usp=sharing)

Comment: A imagem trunc03.jpg é um caso onde ocorreu o problema.

Comment: @Everson "Truncando seria cortando uma informação ou seria que como há 2 usuários mexendo no mesmo registro acaba sobrescrevendo o do outro?"
Pelo que consegui entender, a edição não era simultânea. Ao que parece, um usuário editava a OS X o outro a OS Y e um deles teve a OS misturada com a do outro...